# Case condition in Sql teradata

Tags: teradata

Below is the table data:

```
Id.         Race
101         White
101         Hispanic
101         Black 
101       Not provided
202      Hispanic
202      Black
202       Asian
303       Not provided 
303       Hispanic
404       Other 
404      not provided
```

Below is the race priority I need to follow and bring it to one row for each ID.

Priority Race

1. ```
     White
   ```
2. ```
     Hispanic
   ```
3. ```
     Black
   ```
4. ```
     Asian
   ```
5. (Notprovided or other) then print null

I am not sure how to partition by ID combining with the race hierarchy condition.

Expected Output:

The output should be

```
ID    race
101  White
202  Hispanic
303  Hispanic 
404  Null
```

Comment: What do the three-digit numbers in your starting data indicate? I know the header is ID but clearly it's not a unique ID. Where does it come from? It's unclear how you logically arrive at the expected output from the displayed starting data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to handle this sort of problem is to encode, aggregate, and decode:

```
SELECT ID, 
  CASE MIN(CASE Race
           WHEN 'White' THEN 1
           WHEN 'Hispanic' THEN 2
           WHEN 'Black' THEN 3
           WHEN 'Asian' THEN 4
           ELSE NULL
           END)
  WHEN 1 THEN 'White'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'Hispanic'
  WHEN 3 THEN 'Black'
  WHEN 4 THEN 'Asian'
  ELSE 'Null' END AS Race
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Id ORDER BY Id;
```

Comment: Thank you, this approach worked !!